# OuputStreamWriter/FileWriter

Tags: кодировка, java

Привет. Мне нужно *дописать* информацию в файл причем с учетом кодировки?
OutputStreamWriter позволяет указать кодировку, но не получается именно ДОПИСАТЬ в файл.
FileWriter позволяет ДОПИСАТЬ в файл, но кодировку указать не позволяет.
Как быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("x.txt", true), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное.